# Custom image "more" tab in iOS and image colors in more items

Tags: ios5, uitabbar

Is there any way to set a custom image for the "more" tab in iOS?

And on the other side the items images that appears when I click in the more tab appears in black. Is there any way to set this image to be in colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to implement a custom tabBar like this.

https://github.com/judges/RXCustomTabBar