# How To Customize 'More' Button of UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I added UITabBarController as RootView and I also know that 'more' button is automatically added when you have more then 5 tabBarItem.

So Its all Work prefect But I have Two Issues:

1) how can i set Image On 'more' TabBarItem ?
2) myTabBarItem Not added properly (see image for more understanding) its only design related issue

[image]

Image says that my i set

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

And My UITabBarItem is Orange Color, So Here you can see that my tabBarItem not fit to UITabBar and also dont know how to add image on 'more' Button.

Please Help my On this Issues.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131351/custom-image-more-tab-in-ios-and-image-colors-in-more-items, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438381/customizing-the-more-menu-on-a-tab-bar

Comment: @woz source code of your link have no 'more' button :(

Comment: It's an alternative method since you can't easily change the more button on UITabBar.

Comment: check out this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571028/changing-tint-background-color-of-uitabbar

Comment: @Poorva- sorry dear, your link cant help me :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't customize **More** button in TabViewController by setting custom image there, this tabbar is supposed to be created automatically by iOS.

Comment: Opsss.. then wt i want to do on this situation because client need application which have more button and also he need to put Image on it... i tried to search on google about 3-4 hour but i can't find my solution :( also i have tabbar design related issue please see my 2) issue at this question :(

Comment: You can create custom tabbar, but I would not recommend to do that. Either you can explain your client/boss/whoever that making more than 5 tabs in tabbar for iPhone will lead to bad user experience (it will be difficult for users to tap on smaller tabs) and is prohibited by Apple.

Comment: thanks for replay, yup will discuss on that issues with my client and also please suggest me on my another issue ..

Comment: Check this guide, it helped me half a year ago - http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-how-to-customize-tab-bar-background-appearance/